Index Page with Hyperlinks
I'm trying to write a simple index page that has a hyperlink for each term. Here's my attempt (with some help from Chatgpt):
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,mathrsfs,mathtools,nicematrix,chngcntr,centernot,ytableau,tikz-cd}
\usepackage{textcomp,tocloft,environ,setspace,geometry,enumerate,enumitem,blindtext,multicol,xcolor,fancyhdr,calligra,graphicx,wrapfig,pgfplots,mdframed,tabularx,lipsum,comment,csquotes,zref-user,imakeidx,etoolbox,xparse,pgffor}

% Initialize a counter for unique labels
\newcounter{cfdcounter}

% Store a list of cfd terms and labels
\newcommand{\cfdlist}{}

% Define the \cfd command to store the term and create a label
\newcommand{\cfd}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{cfdcounter}% Increment the counter for each \cfd{}
  \label{cfd:\thecfdcounter}% Create a label with the counter
  \xdef\cfdlist{\cfdlist#1}% Append the term and label to the list
  {\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont{#1}\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont{}}
}

% Define the \hindex command to generate an enumerated list with hyperlinks
\newcommand{\hindex}{%
  \newsection{Index} % This creates the Index section
  \def\templist{\cfdlist} % Use the list of terms stored
    \foreach \term in \templist {%
      \splitter{\term}{|}% Split by delimiter (counter and term)
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \hyperlink{cfd:\tempa}{\tempa} \\% Create the hyperlink for each item
  \end{enumerate}
    }
   % End the enumerate list
}

% Helper command to split the list by a delimiter
\newcommand{\splitter}[2]{%
  \def\tempa{#1}% First part (counter) goes in #1
  \def\tempb{#2}% Second part (term) goes in #2
}

\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\begin{document}

This is a \cfd{topological space}. This is a \cfd{topology}. This topology is \cfd{finer}.

\hindex
\end{document}

However, the result looks like:

What I want:

Any idea for fixing this? Thanks in advance!

Welcome to TeX SE. Could you expand your code to make it compilable? It will be easier to help you out.

your question is not very clear and you have only posted a fragfment of code with no context. Always post a complete small document that shows the problem. standard index commands with hyperref should produce a hyperlinked index, what do you want to differently, what is the intention of the code shown?

I edit the question so it should be clear now. Thanks for the advice.

The code posted produces no output, just errors on line one due to missing documentclass

Also do you want an (english) index or as seems possible an (english) table of contents, which is called index in some European languages such as Italian ?

@DavidCarlisle I am sorry I forgot to copy the documentclass line, now it should work. I think I may need more European languages to include some theorem names. I choose not to use imakeidx package because I wrote '\pagenumbering{gobble}' before, so '\printindex' does not work.

I'm sorry I really can not guess what you intend the code you post to do or what your output shows, it appears just to be an enumerated list, what do the numbers represent, what hyperlink do you want to make if topology appears twice?. \pagenumbering{gobble} has never been a documented way of getting no page numbers, \pagestyle{empty} would be more standard but either way an index is an alphabetical list of words and (separately) links to the places they are used. I can see nothing that looks like an index in either the code or your requested output.

standard indices do not have to link to page numbers, they can link to other things eg doc package indices liknk to code line numbers.

do you want to close this question as you have asked a new one that seems to be the same?
